# O is the orthocentre of △ABC if and only if AP⊥BC, BR⊥AC and CQ⊥AB. Prove that angle OPQ= angle OPR

Tags: education

enter link description here

O is the orthocentre of △ABC if and only if AP⊥BC, BR⊥AC and CQ⊥AB. Prove that angle OPQ= angle OPR

Comment: What are $P$, $Q$, and $R$?  How are they related to $O$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. We encourage askers to show their work and tell us what stumps him/her. Please add more details, or the question would highly likely to be closed soon. Also we do not reccmmend to include links in your post except wiki’s or other questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is only angle chasing, $\angle OPC=90^{\circ}$. Also, $\angle RPC =BAC$ because $ARPB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. In the same way $\angle QPB = \angle BAC$. From this point, the conclusion follows.[image]